# can not post in sub site multisite

Tags: php, wordpress

I just configured my Wordpress site as multisite with a sub directory, everything is working fine, but the problem is when I post a new post in the sub site it displays a page for new post, but after clicking Publish nothing happens. It is working if using document root `/public_html/wp/`.

I didn't find this problem on Google after searching for 5 hours.

`.htacess` file is working with document root `/public_html/domain.com/wp/` and also in `/public_html/domain.com/`. There are 2 `.htacess` files, 1st for `domain.com` and 2nd for wordpress which is installed in wp directory.

My domain `.htacess` is:

```
# -FrontPage-

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName domain.com
AuthUserFile /home/theindep/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/theindep/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) wp/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ wp/$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

and 2nd `.htacess` for wordpress is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) wp/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ wp/$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

And `WP-Config.php`:

```
define ('WPLANG', '');
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );


define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'domain.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);


/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
include_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/feed2.php');
```

Comment: And you get no errors after clicking the button?
Nothing happens?

Comment: thanks for your consideration, no i didn't get any error

Comment: You have named the files `.htaccess`...right? The fact that you have called it `.htacess` in the whole question makes me ask.